# Exibir dados em Array

Tags: php, aplicação-web, firebird

Estou fazendo uma consulta em um banco de dados e preciso exibir as informações na tela, porém buscando de um em um. Tentei fazer por array, porém ele não está exibindo o vetor.

Código:

```
<?php
$a = $_GET['a'];
if($a == "buscar"){
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $sql = ibase_query("SELECT NOME FROM TB_CLIENTE WHERE ID_CLIENTE LIKE '%".$id."%'");
  $row = ibase_fetch_row($sql);
  $vetorDados = array();
  $i=0;
  $vetorDados[$i]= ibase_fetch_row($sql);
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>' . $vetorDados[$i] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $i . '</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
  $i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faltou você criar um `while` para exibir dados, outro detalhe que ficou redundante foi você criar um array `$vetorDados` para imprimir o resultado do banco, sendo que a variável `$row` já é um `array`, abaixo segue o código para exibir os dados do banco.

```
<?php
$a = $_GET['a'];
if($a == "buscar"){
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql = ibase_query("SELECT NOME FROM TB_CLIENTE WHERE ID_CLIENTE LIKE '%".$id."%'");
$i = 1;
while($row = ibase_fetch_row($sql)){
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>{$row['NOME']}</td>";
   echo "<td>{$i}</td>"; 
   echo "</tr>";
   $i++;
   }    
}
?>
```

A chave da variável `$row` é o nome da coluna do banco a qual você deseja imprimir a informação.

Comment: @ProgMen eu havia esquecido de fechar a `tag </tr>`

Comment: Entao, anteriormente eu estava fazendo assim, porem ai ele busca "todos" os nomes com aqele id, e se eu busco outro ele apaga o anterior, eu queria q ele fosse fazendo uma lista conforme iria adicionando

Comment: Veja se entendi, você que criar uma lista como se fosse um histórico dos ultimos registros buscados?

Comment: Isso,conforme vou dando mais ids eles vao aparecendo em ordem na tela, do jeito q estou fazendo, cada valor q eu entro ele apaga o anterior.
 `if($a == "buscar"){
                $id = $_POST['id'];
                $sql = ibase_query("SELECT NOME FROM TB_CLIENTE WHERE ID_CLIENTE = $id ");
                $row = ibase_fetch_row($sql);
                   echo '<tr>';
                   echo '<td>' . $row[0] . '</td>';
                   echo '</tr>';
              }`

Comment: @ProgMen entendi, mas dessa forma não é possível utilizando `php` para que ele funcione dessa forma precisa usar `jquery` ou  `javascript` que vai criando uma lista dinâmica no `innerHTML` dessa forma você deve concluir está pergunta e criar uma nova, solicitando auxilio quando a criar uma lista dinamica ordenada com dados de busca.

Comment: Perfeitamente, obrigado! Nao sabia haha, achava q php faria isso. obrigado.

Comment: Irei fazer a pergunta, pode me ajudar por la ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67249/discussion-between-wmomesso-and-progmen).